# Data modeling(Prediction, categorization) : continuous & discrete Input, discrete output

Tags: r, statistics

I have sample data as following.

```
In.1   In.2   In.3  In.Category    Out
 1.5    2.4    1.9            A      A
 3.8   51.5    5.2            A      B
82.2    3.3   48.5            B      B
10.1    1.0    2.8            C      B
18.8   48.6   85.1            A      C
```

Remark

```
In.1~In.3 : Continous Value (Numeric)
In.Category : Discrete

Out : Discrete
In.Category value is not relevant to Out value.(They are not the same)
```

I want to find a rule based on the sample data. And if I get more input data, I'd like to predict what Out value is going to be. (I personaly assume that it might be related to clustering, classification or association rule)

What kind of statistic modeling should be applied?

Would you please give me an example source code in R? (At least pseudo code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answer:

I assume that `Random Forest` should be applied.

Please refer the link below

[Computational Prediction](http://mkseo.pe.kr/stats/?p=220#viewSource)